# How to check retrieve key is previously retrieved or not and act as?

Tags: java

I retrieve key from online if that key previously retrieved than break loop else if that key retrieves first time than call a method and that key store in string array for check same after.

```
    String[] keyArray = new String[1000];
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        fire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(84.1616328, 23.8476036), i)
                .addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                        //String[] keyArray= new String[10];
                        int x = 0;
                        int k =0;
                        for(int j=0;j<keyArray.length;j++) {
                            if (keyArray[j].equals(" ")) { //java.lang.NullPointerException
                                k = j;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                if (key.equals(keyArray[j])) {
                                    x = 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (x != 1){
                            keyArray[k+1]=key;
                            Log.i("key", key);
                            getItems(key); // Method call for retrieve Firebase Database

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // For find out nearby user GeoFire key by loop searching
    ArrayList<String> keyArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=2000;i++) { // Here i=1 means 1 is kilometer radius
        fire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(84.1616328, 23.8476036), i)
                .addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                        int x = 0;
                         for(int j=0;j<keyArray.size();j++) {
                            if (keyArray.get(j).equals(" ")) {
                               break;
                            }else{
                                if (key.equals(keyArray.get(j))) {
                                    x = 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (x != 1){
                            keyArray.add(key);
                            Log.i("key", key);
                            getItems(key); // Method call for retrieve Firebase Database

                        }
                    }
```